# Dictionary of dictionaries from list of lists with year keys

Tags: python

I have a list of list like this:

```
[['2014', 'MALE', 'WHITE NON HISPANIC', 'Zachary', '90', '39'], 
['2014', 'MALE', 'WHITE NON HISPANIC', 'Zev', '49', '65']]
```

I want to  converted in a dictionary like  this:

```
{{2012: {1: 'David',
  2: 'Joseph',
  3: 'Michael',
  4: 'Moshe'},
2013: {1: 'David',
  2: 'Joseph',
  3: 'Michael',
  4: 'Moshe'},
```

I'm trying to do a  list comprehension like this:

```
boy_names = {row[0]:{i:row[3]} for i,row in enumerate(records) if row[1]=='MALE'}
```

But the result I'm getting is  like:

```
{'2011': {7851: 'Zev'}, '2012': {9855: 'Zev'}, 
'2013': {11886: 'Zev'}, '2014': {13961: 'Zev'}}
```

If I'm right, I think I'm taking the last value and its row number from enumerate by the year key, but no idea how to solve it.

Comment: base the dict you want to have on the "demo" input `[['2014', 'MALE', 'WHITE NON HISPANIC', 'Zachary', '90', '39'], 
['2014', 'MALE', 'WHITE NON HISPANIC', 'Zev', '49', '65']]`

Comment: No idea what's you mean.

Comment: You can't use dict-comprehension here because you are adding items to keys you build along the way. You will have to do a loop but a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will make for a clean code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the length of the sub-dict under the year key to calculate the next incremental numeric key for the sub-dict under the current year. Use the `dict.setdefault` method to default the value of a new key to an empty dict:

```
boy_names = {}
for year, _, _, name, _, _ in records:
    record = boy_names.setdefault(int(year), {})
    record[len(record) + 1] = name
```

Comment: Do you know why I'm having an error when selecting keys like this "boy_names[2014].keys()"?

Comment: This is because years are strings in your input and yet you expect them to be integers in the output. I've updated the answer so that years are converted to integers then.

Comment: blhsing you're the best! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need

```
data = [['2014', 'MALE', 'WHITE NON HISPANIC', 'Zachary', '90', '39'], 
['2014', 'MALE', 'WHITE NON HISPANIC', 'Zev', '49', '65']]

result = {}
for i in data:           #Iterate sub-list
    result.setdefault(i[0], []).append(i[3])   #Form DICT
    
result = {k: dict(enumerate(v, 1)) for k, v in result.items()}   #Use enumerate to get index number
print(result)
# {'2014': {1: 'Zachary', 2: 'Zev'}}
```

Comment: Thank you too Rakesh!